# Why do the roc_auc scores for train_test_split and for cross-validation differ so much?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, scikit-learn

When I used scikit-learn pipeline and cross-validation, I got an average cv roc_auc score of about 0.78. But when I used train_test_split, I got a test roc_auc score of only 0.54. The difference is so huge, and I don't know what went wrong. Is there any problem with my pipeline and cv? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I got it. It's my roc_auc_score. The correct code should use pipe.predict_proba(X_test).
[image]